# Error ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis because of concatenating dataframes

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn

I implemented experimental environment in my project.

This component is based on Scikit learn.

In this compnent I read the given CSV into pandas dataframe. 
After that I selected the best features and reduced the dimensions of the given dataframe from 100 to 5. 
After that I added to this reduced dataframe the removed ID column for future use. This coloumn was dropped by the dimension reduction process.

Everything works fine until I changed my code to read all CSV files and return one union dataframe:

Please look on the next code:
Reading all CSV:

```
dataframes = []

from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
files_names = [f for f in listdir(full_path_directory_files) if   isfile(join(full_path_directory_files, f))]
for file_name in files_names:
    full_path_file = full_path_directory_files + file_name

    data_frame = pd.read_csv(full_path_file, index_col=None, compression="infer")
dataframes.append(dataframe)
```

After that I made concatenation between the dataframes

```
features_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=0)
```

I also checked it. 
I created two different dataframes with shape = (200, 100)
and after concatenating it turned to (400, 100)

After that the dataframe was sent into the following method:

```
 def _reduce_dimensions_by_num_of_features(self, features_dataframe, truth_dataframe, num_of_features):
    print("Create dataframe with the {0} best features".format(num_of_features))

## In those functions I got the ids and their class

    ids, id_series = self._create_ids_by_dataframe(features_dataframe)
    features_dataframe_truth_class = self._extract_truth_class_by_truth_dataframe(truth_dataframe, ids)


    k_best_classifier = SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k=num_of_features)
    k_best_features = k_best_classifier.fit_transform(features_dataframe, features_dataframe_truth_class)

    reduced_dataframe_column_names = self._get_k_best_feature_names(k_best_classifier, features_dataframe)


    reduced_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(k_best_features, columns=reduced_dataframe_column_names)
```

Now I retrieved the ID column:

```
    reduced_dataframe["Id"] = id_series
```

The software it failed on the message:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

This is occurred only after the concation of the dataframes.

How can I add the column of the IDs into the dataframe without getting error??

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem:

After the concatenation of the dataframes, the index is changed and when we add the row :

```
reduced_dataframe["Id"] = id_series
```

We got an error.

The solution is to reset the index :

```
features_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=0)
features_dataframe.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```